# ¿Como cuadrar mis cartas de un mismo largo en Bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Ya que cada carta tiene un contenido variado el largo de las cartas queda descuadrado, no he podido solucionar que la carta con menos contenido quede del mismo largo que la que esta al lado, o bueno del mismo largo que la carta que tiene mas contenido.
Imagen de refenrencia:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo:

````
  <span class="border border-light bg-primary">
    <h1 id="proyectos-titulo">Proyectos Realizados</h1>
  </span>
  <!--Primera Carta--> 
  <div class="col-sm-6 my-3">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">CRUD python-django</h5>
        <p class="card-text">CRUD completo con Python, Django y una base de datos SQLite3, usando el patrón de arquitectura 
          MTV (Modelo - Plantilla - Vista), el ORM de Django, el Framework CSS Bootstrap y control de eventos con JavaScript.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">HTML CSS Bootstrap Django SQLite3 JavaScript</small></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 container-fluid ">
        <img src="assets/images/projects/vista1.png" class="card-img-bottom" alt="...">
        <a href="https://github.com/juliancape/CRUD-python-django" class="btn btn-primary my-1" target="_blank">Link</a>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--Segunda Carta--> 
  <div class="col-sm-6 my-3 ">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Blog python-django</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Blog con Python y django, los post son guardados en una base de datos SQLite3, se uso el patrón de arquitectura 
          MTV (Modelo - Plantilla - Vista), el ORM de Django y para el front-end se utilizo el framework Bootstrap, además se puede ver mas a 
          detalle el post que llame la atención. 
        </p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">HTML CSS Bootstrap Django SQLite3</small></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 container-fluid ">
        <img src="assets/images/projects/blog.png" class="card-img-bottom" alt="...">
        <a href="https://github.com/juliancape/blog-python-django" class="btn btn-primary my-1" target="_blank">Link</a>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div> ```
````

Comment: `height: max-content`

Comment: Por que tienes columnas y sin sus filas ?

Answer (score 1):

Como mencioné en el comentario, no veo por que tener columnas sin tener sus respectivas filas...

Segundo, agregue el resto del contenido en un contenedor, en el cual a las cards les aplique `d-flex align-items-stretch`.

`d-flex` para que se organizen una al lado de la otra

`align-items-stretch` para estirar el contenido dentro de ellas

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<span class="border border-light bg-primary">
  <h1 id="proyectos-titulo">Proyectos Realizados</h1>
</span>
<!--Primera Carta-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 my-3 d-flex align-items-stretch">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">CRUD python-django</h5>
          <p class="card-text">CRUD.</p>
          <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">HTML CSS Bootstrap Django SQLite3 JavaScript</small></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 container-fluid ">
          <img src="assets/images/projects/vista1.png" class="card-img-bottom" alt="...">
          <a href="https://github.com/juliancape/CRUD-python-django" class="btn btn-primary my-1" target="_blank">Link</a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!--Segunda Carta-->
    <div class="col-sm-6 my-3 d-flex align-items-stretch">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Blog python-django</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Blog con Python y django, los post son guardados en una base de datos SQLite3, se uso el patrón de arquitectura
            MTV (Modelo - Plantilla - Vista), el ORM de Django y para el front-end se utilizo el framework Bootstrap, además se puede ver mas a
            detalle el post que llame la atención.
          </p>
          <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">HTML CSS Bootstrap Django SQLite3</small></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 container-fluid ">
          <img src="assets/images/projects/blog.png" class="card-img-bottom" alt="...">
          <a href="https://github.com/juliancape/blog-python-django" class="btn btn-primary my-1" target="_blank">Link</a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```